# how to reinitialize base class in c++

Tags: c++

I have derived class and base class. in the constructor of the derived class I have to use the basic constructor of the base class. Then later on I want to re-construct the base class with deiffernet base class constructor :

```
class A
{
public:
    int a, b;
}

class B : public A
{
    B() : A()
    {
...
    //do some calculations to calculate a and b and then 
   //re-construct class A with the right values.
       A(a,b) <--- ????
    }

}
```

how to I do that ?

Comment: so why don't you change the fields after your calculation? why don't you take the calculation before you create your object?

Comment: Why would you do this and not initialize your base class with the right values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constructors are meant to create objects. Hence they are used once. You should create a method to do initialization and call that from constructors.

Answer (score 2):

You could provide a copy and/or move assignment operations in `class A`.

```
class A
{
public:
    int a, b;

    // Copy assignment operator
    A& operator=(const A& rhs) {
        if(this == &rhs) return *this;
        a = rhs.a; b = rhs.b;
        return *this;
    }

    // ...
};
```

After the above you could reinitialize it using the pattern

```
BaseClass::operator=(BaseClass(a,b));
```

which, in your case is

```
A::operator=(A(a,b));
```

If your class is an aggregate, or has an implicitly defined copy constructor, you should use those (you don't have to define your own), and use the same reinitialization pattern as above.

Comment: why don't we use move semantics here? to me, reinitializiation means, dropping the source object

Answer (score 2):

As others already pointed out, you can only call inhereted constructors in the initialization list of your current constructor, or (in C++11) delegate to other constructors of your current class. This is the only place where you can *initialize* your class.

## init method

In some cases it makes sense to add in `init()` method, which re-initializes parts of your class. This is called two-phase-initialization. You will find it in some window-managing-APIs.

It is important to note that your object is then separated into two parts: The one that is usefully initialized in the c'tor, and the other that is initialized in `init()`. You must (must, must must!) initialize both parts in a way that the object is in a consistent state -- in must never be in an invalid state. As a rule of thumb: If the object is created (by a c'tor), then a **destructor call** must always possible. Specificly: Don't leave any pointers and handles lying around with random values.

```
class ChildWindow : Compontent {
    shared_ptr<Component> parent_;  // builds the component hierarchy
    Component[]        children_;   // child cp'nts, unknown during c'tor 
    size_t            nchildren_;   // ...use e vector in real code!        
public:
    ChildWindow(chared_ptr<>Component> parent)
      : parent_(parent),
        children(nullptr), nchildren(0) // MUST initialize
    {}
    void addChild(Component *child) { /*... change children_ ...*/ }
    void init() {
        if(nchildren > 0) { /* ...throw away old ... */ }
        children_ = new Component[...];
        // ... init children_ with nulls
    }
};
```

This is only a rough idea where you may use two-phase initialization.

## Wrapper

If you really just need to re-initialize everything, a technical solution might to use a simple wrapper class around you real object:

```
class WindowWrapper {
    Window *window_;
public:
    WindowWrapper() : window_(nullptr) {}
    void reset() { delete window_; window_ = nullptr; }
    Window& get() { return *window_; }
    Window& operator*() { return get(); }
}
```

...typed down off-hand, probably some errors in it. This is why there **already is such a wrapper** in C++11:

```
unique_ptr<Window> win { new Window{parent, "title"} };
// ..use win...
win.reset( new Window{otherparent, "other title"} };
```

And if this `unique_ptr` is not enough you could put this inside the above wrapper.

## The error

Just as a side note, To explain what the code you wrote does:

```
B::B() : A() { 
   A(a,b); // <--- ????
}
```

When you type line "????", you create a *temporary object of type `A`, which disappears on function exit. It does *not* call any destructor on your current object.

Why does it create a temp object? Well, you can write

```
A a(a,b);
```

as a statement and you get a new instance `a` of class `A`, constructed with the a c'tor with two arguments. This `a` you could use in another function call, say `func(a);`. But you can spare that explicit variable `a` by just leaving out its name:

```
func(A(a,b));
```

calls `func` with an unnamed ("temporary") object of class `A`, which disappears at the end of the statement (i.e. `;`).

And these kind of *temp objects* you can create as an expression. And since every *expression* is also a *statement*

```
A(a,b);
```

is a valid statement -- creating a temp object, which immediately vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the constructor of your superclass except in your initializer list. You have to use composition instead of inheritance if you want to use operations on a differrently constructed A object. If a method changes an already constructed object, it is not a contructor. So either replace the object with a newly constructed one (instead of changing it) or use non constructor methods.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code to compute a and b into a method and use it in the initializer list:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a, int b): a_(a), b_(b) {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(): A(B::computeA(), B::computeB()) {}

private:
    static int computeA();
    static int computeB();
};
```

I have made the methods static to prevent using a partially initialized object.

Although I have to say that the question and the example sound like you are using inheritance to re-use an implementation. In this case, you should not use inheritance but composition and replace the inheritance with a member object.